# Calculate the center point of multiple Lat/Long

Tags: javascript, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I am using Google Map to display multiple lat/long points.

But the Google map Javascript code has the code snippet to track the center of lat/long of the available lat/long.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($data);?>'); //alert (locations);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][1]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
</script>
```

In Above code the line

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(),
```

needs a lat/long pair which could be the center point of multiple lat/long to be displayed.

How could that be done?

Comment: If you lat/longs define an irregular polygon then there is no official defined 'centre'. See this: http://www.mathopenref.com/polygoncenter.html It states the centre as "The point inside a regular polygon that is equidistant from each vertex.". You will see later it says it can have a `centroid`. Here is a 7 step process for that. http://www.ehow.com/how_7209923_calculate-centroid-polygon.html - obviously wiki has some good stuff on this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid)

Comment: Is _(mean lat, mean long)_ not good enough?

Comment: Exact same question was asked two weeks ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085275/calculate-the-center-of-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates

Answer (score 3):

This works.  See the documentation of [Map.fitBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) and [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) for details:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var locations =  JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($data);?>');//alert (locations);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2],locations[i][3]),
        map: map
      });
      bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][1]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  </script>
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var locations = JSON.parse(
  JSON.stringify([
    ['AAA', 'BBB', 42, -72],
    ['BBB', 'CCC', 42.1, -72.2]
  ])); //alert (locations);
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
    map: map
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][1]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the bounds of your added markers with the function map.getBounds().

It returns an object on which you can get the center bound.getCenter().

See [Find center of multiple locations in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634199/find-center-of-multiple-locations-in-google-maps)